# How do I solve for n: $\dfrac{2}{9}(n^2-n)\times0.6^n=0.121$

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

So I need to solve this equation as a part of a binomial distribution problem:

> Complete Question: Over a one moth period, Ava and Sven play a total of x games of tennis. The probability that Ava wins any game $0.4$. The result of each game played is independent of any other game played. Let X denote the number of games won by Ava over a one month period.
>
> (a) Find an expression for $P(X = 2)$ in terms of $n$.
>
> (b) If the probability that Ava wins two games in 0.121 correct to 3 d.p., find the value on $n$.

$\dfrac{2}{9}(n^2-n)\times0.6^n=0.121$

I've tried to simplify it by multiplying both sides by $\dfrac{9}{2}$:

$$(n^2-n)\times0.6^n=0.5445$$
Now I'm stuck, I tried using logarithms but I didn't get anywhere.
The answer should be very close to $10$. Does anyone have a hint on how to proceed? Thank you.

Comment: W|A can't solve it... (algebraically) [here] (http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+%28x^2-x%29*.6^x+%3D+0.5445)

Comment: @anorton So what do you think I should do? This question is a medium difficulty one, and I am sure the equation is right, because it was part a of the question.

Comment: You're *absolutely sure* you're supposed to *solve* the equation for $n$?

Comment: are you sure its 0.6^n and not 0.6^2n?

Comment: Yes, part a of the question is: Find an expression for $P(X=2)$ in terms of n. Probability of ava winning is 0.4. The answer is the equation is the LHS of the equation. Part b says: "If the probability that Ava wins two games is 0.121 correct to 3 d.p. find the value of n.

Comment: Is $n$ integer?

Comment: $n$ is an integer since a number of trials are whole numbers, also $n=10$

Comment: @HansGroeffen Can you edit the question to include the whole question?

Comment: @anorton The whole question is now included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since n is known to be an integer, I believe the only way you can get n=10 is through trial & error with your simplified equation.

@anorton: Wolfram can actually solve the equation to get n=9.9981.

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+%28n%5E2-n%29*%280.6%5En%29+%3D+0.5445